# Excel Worksheet used Range Count is to big C#

Tags: c#, excel, worksheet

I've got a problem with my `.UsedRange.Count` in my code.
I try to count the used rows in my Worksheet to define a `Range` from the first Value row of the Sheet to the last. For this I need to get the used `Rows` in my Worksheet and I try to do it with

```
this.worksheet.UsedRange.Count
```

But the Result is to big. My Worksheet just got 140 Rows and `.UsedRange.Count` is counting something above 100.000

Also

```
this.worksheet.Rows.Count
```

won´t work. The result is something near 100.000

Comment: for better understanding, request you to share the block of code where you are trying to perform this action.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark: are there formulas in the "empty" cells? Not sure, but maybe Excel consider those as used, even the formula validates to empty.

Comment: Excel can consider rows and columns as being used even if they are empty. Try selecting all rows below the data you want to keep and deleting them. Same for columns. You can also press Ctrl+End to jump to where Excel things the bottom right of your data is.

Comment: @dba there are no formulars. But i´ve got Filters in the Excel sheet, could this maybe excel consider the column as used?

Comment: @DavidG when i pess in my Excel Ctrl+End i get to row 158, so not like the result of the code

Comment: To the Filter comment:
i made the AutoFilterMode = false but still get something over 100k

Comment: @TomiHorvath tested every column?

Comment: @dba I´ve also tried to call just a single column. For example:
this.worksheet.Range["A1"].EntireColumn.Rows.Count

Comment: try [this](https://contexturesblog.com/archives/2012/03/01/select-actual-used-range-in-excel-sheet/#:~:text=Select%20the%20Used%20Range,to%20the%20last%20used%20cell.) to confirm used range

Comment: @dba If i´m doing this in my Excel runnig, i end up at Row nr.158, but my Code calls something above 100k

Comment: please show your class, which you refer as `this`

Comment: This ist just a field i initialised

Comment: Holy... So you problem was you compared the Rowcont with the Cellcount and wondered, why they didn't match :-) I think, that blended all of us :-)

Answer (score 0):

Solved the Problem:
However `this.worksheet.UsedRange.Count` is multiplying the Rows with the Columns (counts all cells that were used)

With `this.worksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count` i just get the Row Count.